# How to return rows only when row in other table is not present

Tags: mysql

I have a view that combines two tables, one is called "projects", the other one "offers". A project can have many offers and a user can make an offer to many projects.

I want to show the user a list of "all" projects (the ones the user already made an offer for) and "new projects" (the ones the user has NOT made an offer for already).

"All" is easy. But I struggle with the "new" list.

I need to have a query that iterates through all projects and only returns the projects that have NO entry in the offers table of the user I want to display the list for (but the table could have other offers or NO OFFERS).

I hope this makes sense to somebody. I was training several hours to get it right …

As a side note: The view so far left joins both tables and returns for every project as many rows as there are offers (the user I want to match the query to is generated at runtime).

Table projects:
project_id
project_owner_id
some other field

Table offers:
offer_id
project_id
offer_maker_id
some other fields

So, in the projects table, there, of course, is no id from the guy making the offer. How can I select now any project where a specific user has not many any offer for?

An inner join does not do the trick because then I get far too many rows back as I get every offer of every project back where the user_id is not the user in question.

Comment: It might be helpful if you posted some code.

Comment: This is basically a left join query

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to write a select statement with a "not in" subquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358028/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-write-a-select-statement-with-a-not-in-subqu)

Answer (score 0):

I keep this graphic posted on my wall for just such questions: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/Database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg  You want the one on the top left (LEFT JOIN)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working query. The join did not do the trick unfortunately.

```
SELECT `project_id`
  FROM `projects`
WHERE `project_id`
  NOT IN (SELECT `project_id`
            FROM `offers`
          WHERE `user_id` = 'foo');
```

So no joins are needed - a simple sub select did the trick.