# MS Access SQL to return values in Table2 that are not found in Table1

Tags: sql, ms-access

I know this is a very trivial question, but I can't seem to find the right commands to get the result shown below. I could not understand how to use `NOT EXIST` or `IN`. Note that I am using MS Access.

The following gives errors:

```
SELECT T2.* FROM T2
WHERE NOT EXIST
(SELECT T1.* FROM T1)
```

I have no one else to ask personally, since I am just learning SQL from YouTube. 
Hope anyone could help me.

```
T1
+-----+------+
| Ind | Val  |
+-----+------+
|  1  |  aa  |
|  2  |  bb  |
+-----+------+

T2
+-----+------+
| Ind | Val  |
+-----+------+
|  1  |  aa  |
|  2  |  bb  |
|  3  |  cc  |
+-----+------+

Result:
+-----+------+
| Ind | Val  |
+-----+------+
|  3  |  cc  |
+-----+------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use a `NOT EXISTS`, you need to specify which columns you're comparing:

```
SELECT T2.* FROM T2
WHERE NOT EXIST
(SELECT 1 FROM T1 WHERE T1.ind = T2.ind AND T1.Val = T2.Val)
```

Comment: Hi @Erik thanks for your help. I tried this, however it returned a table without any rows. Also what is the use of 'SELECT 1'?

Comment: Based on your sample data, it should return rows. `SELECT 1` just selects a value (namely 1). You need to select a value for the clause to work, using `1` is convention.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use JOIN. It is much more useful and will work faster on larger tables. More joins [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9Pln.png).

```
select *
from T1 a
right join T2 b on b.key = a.key
where a.key is null
```

Comment: Hi @Mr. No thanks for your help. I tried this however it prompts for a value. Also the rows do not have a primary key.

Comment: `JOIN`s certainly aren't faster than `NOT EXISTS`. `NOT EXISTS` gets optimized by the optimizer to an `ANTI JOIN`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1358038/7296893), not exists is often the fastest and right way.